# How does C++ know which '++' operator to call?

Tags: c++

I'm dabbing with C++ here and this question poped up when looking at some operator overloading functions.
In the functions below, I understand that the int parameter in the second function is just a way to provide a different signature, allowing for the first function to be called if the prefix increment is used, and the second one for suffix increment (according to the book I'm reading).

```
const_iterator & operator++ ( )
{
    current = current->next;
    return *this;
}

const_iterator operator++ ( int )
{
    const_iterator old = *this;
    ++( *this );
    return old;
}
```

As the calls to the functions are in the form of ++itr and itr++ with no parameter passed, how does the language know which one to call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write `++itr`, the compiler translates it into `itr.operator++()` and the first function is called. If you write `itr++`, the compiler translates it into `itr.operator++(0)` and the second function is called.

You can also implement `operator++` as a non-member function, though this is rarely done. In such cases, the translations will be, respectively, `operator++(itr)` and `operator++(itr, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you! It became clear now with your explanation and the link provided by the other user.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you know what is post-increment and pre-increment? `i++` is post-increment and `++i` is pre-increment. So in compiler there literally if statement, that boils down if `varName` is followed by `++` call `operator++ (var)` if you see `++` followed by variable name call `operator++ ()`.